# How can I combine all the emails into my website?

Tags: php, pim

I'm doing my FYP about personal information management. 
I want to enable user to check their different email accounts in my website. is it possible? how can I do it?
I'm using Mysql and PHP to develop the site.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. PHP has built-in support for [POP3 and IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) protocols. Those protocols are the only thing you need to remotely check a electronic mailbox.

Comment: Thank you! what about the facebook feeds and twitter tweet? as well as  RSS feeds. basically, I want user can search all their personal information at one click.

Comment: For Facebook feeds, you need to learn the Facebook API. It's also perfectly possible. The same applies for Twitter timeline. RSS feeds is just an XML, so you can perfectly do it as well.